# Sanitizing existing media library paths and page links from foreign characters

Tags: uploads, media, migration

I'm migrating an old WP site that supported Swedish letters ÅÄÖ in the URL, thus the site has hundrets of images containing these letters. I've searched around and found various plugins that sanitize all *new* uploaded media, but how could I go through all the old media and fix their media entries a long with their links on various pages?

Currently the files are also still also using their original filenames. I'm thinking some combination of a renaming command over SSH and some SQL commands on the database maybe?

Answer (score 0):

just a guess: maybe a thumbnail regenerator plugin will work in combination your sanitize plugin.

like this [regenerate-thumbnails](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) or this [force-regenerate-thumbnails](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/)